# publishing multiple apks for a android app

Tags: android

Is googleplay allowing the developer to publish multiple apk for single app?  I am developing three apks for a single app for supporting different devices. can i upload all apks in google play?

Comment: What did you find when you searched for "google play multiple apk"? Here's what I found: https://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks.html

Comment: I want to reduce the size of apk. So i developed three apks for normal, small , large screens. But google play allows the developer to upload only one apk with same package name. that's why i am asking.

Comment: You can always use layout hdpi, layout xhdpi, layout mdpi to create views of differrent screen sizes. Android os will automatically take the layout for the screen from corresponding folder. You dont need 3 APKs if screen size is your only concern.

Comment: Skt. If i do that, the size of the apk is high. And i have to place the images in x,y position  based on some calculation. It won't be fit for all screen sizes.

Answer (score 1):

Contrary to what the previous answer said, you can do that and set the filters based on different criteria, among others the screen size.

You need to switch your APK screen in developer console to advanced mode to do that (the button is on the right hand side of the screen).