# Publishing multiple versions of Android app as one app

Tags: android

This is my first attempt at publishing an Android app, and I'm hoping I haven't totally &*$#'d the pooch. I've designed an app that is intended to run as one app. However, the purchaser can buy different pieces of data (from a SQLite database) depending on their interests. Specifically, a knitter can buy information on different sets of stitches depending on their ability level. However, no matter what pieces of data they buy, the app, as I said, is intended to run as one app because a knitter may want to purchase more than one set of stitches. I've got my beta-testers lined up, and now I discover that I can't publish multiple apps with the same package name. Does package name = apk name? I don't want to publish apps with different apk names, because then they'll run as different apps. I've seen on Android's site something called In-App Billing, but it requires me to write additional code, and as I said, I've got my beta-testers lined up, so I don't want to delay this any further. Is In-App the only way to go with this? [I saw something on stackoverflow about setting up a library with multiple packages.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15184295/publishing-same-app-with-different-names-in-the-play-store) Would that solve my problem? [I also found an answer that references the Advanced Mode in the Developer Console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18651232/publishing-multiple-apks-for-a-android-app). Is this the solution to my problem? Any clarification would be more than welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does package name = apk name?

No, application packname is different that uniquely identify your app. There is no linking between them.

You can publish multiple APK of your single app with same package name under same app but you should go through the InAppPurchase for purchase stuff etc.

Comment: Thanks, TGMCians! So in my case, should I create multiple versions of my APK with different package names? To change the package name, do I just change the package statement in the manifest, or is there something else I need to do?

Comment: @Melanie IMO, In App Purchase is good for these stuff ie buy. You can see this link for multiple APK support http://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks.html